# ExtJS 3.4 - Submit FormPanel with Grid information

Tags: forms, grid, submit, extjs3

I have a `FormPanel` and in the `formpanel` there is an `Grid` with a Checkbox-Column.

After the selection of some rows, I want to submit the whole `panel` with the information of the `grid`.

I do the submit by pressing a `button` with the following code:

```
mergeCaseForm.getForm().submit({
```

But the information of the `grid` would not be submitted.

It's that possible to submit the `grid` information also?

Thanks and Regards,
Chris